# How to hide just this element

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, parent-child

I want to hide just one element, or remove it, but the problem is that I have many elements with same class?

Here is example

```
<div onclick="parentNode.remove()" class="slikezamenjanje"><img src="1.png"/></div>
<div onclick="parentNode.remove()" class="slikezamenjanje"><img src="2.png"/></div>
<div onclick="parentNode.remove()" class="slikezamenjanje"><img src="1.png"/></div>
<div onclick="parentNode.remove()" class="slikezamenjanje"><img src="2.png"/></div>
```

When I click on element all elements are removed, I don't want that, I just want to delete one element on what I have clicked on, any simple ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `this.remove()` or simply `remove()` instead, you are removing parent of the element, when the parent is removed it's children are removed too.
http://jsfiddle.net/ncLhf/

If you are using jQuery, you can remove the `onclick` attributes and use jQuery `.on()` method instead:

```
$('.slikezamenjanje').on('click', function() {
    // this.remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```